# Confusion with index value of insertSubView

Tags: iphone, ios, view

I understand the insertSubView will insert a new view at some index of the View hierarchy of an iPhone app.

I also understand that

insertSubView atIndex:[[self.view subviews] count]

will insert the subView at the very top so that it's the only visible view. This is akin to addSubview.

However, I'm still a newbie and I'm a bit confused with what is included in a "View".

I have a root controller, and in its view there are 3 buttons on it.

[image: root view]

I was playing around with addSubView in order to understand how it worked, and when I did insertSubview atIndex:1, I got the following:

[image: index 1]

It looks like the new view that I added was added after button 1, but before button 2 and button 3.  If I change the index to 2, then only button 3 shows up, so it appears that the new view is being placed after button 1 and 2 but before 3.

Why is that?  Why do the buttons have individual subview indexes?  I would have thought that everything contained in my root controller's view would fall under a single view.  Are they somehow separate?

Answer (score 2):

What you see is exactly correct. You add button1, then button2 , and then button3. So the stack of view would be:

button3 -> index 2 
button2 -> index 1 
button1 -> index 0.

Now if you do : insertSubview:atIndex:1, you get:

button3 -> index 3 
button2 -> index 2 
AnotherView -> index 1 
button1 -> index 0.

so that only button2 and button3 is visible, because button1 got hidden because "AnotherView" is overlapping its frame.

Similiarly if you do : insertSubview:atIndex:2, you get:

button3 -> index 3 
AnotherView -> index 2 
button2 -> index 1 
button1 -> index 0.

now only button3 is visible, because both button1 and button2 got hidden because "AnotherView" is overlapping their frame.

One more thing you have to consider is that, the z-index alone won't decide which views will be visible. Only if the top view has a frame that covers the below one, the below view would be hidden. From the pictures you have posted, it seems that the frame of the buttons is just big enough to show the text and doest not occupy the whole window's frame

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But why are the buttons separate views?  Wouldn't the entire "root view" (the first image) be a single view together?  Or are each individual item in a view a separate index?

Is there a way to group all the buttons together along with the View so that it would be considered a single view index?

Comment: I am not aware of any grouping of views. However you can use a small trick, where in, use a plain `View` as a holder for all the buttons. you add all the buttons you wanted to be grouped into that `holderView` and add `holderView` to the root view. Now if you want to hide or show the buttons, you can simply hide/show the `holderView`